# Passing number as props in React becomes Object object

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send a number as props in React. When I access it it is not a number, it is Object object. I know that an object in JS is {} but in this context I expect a number not an object.

Here is the value

```
<button onClick={this.showNumber} value={1}>
```

Here is the function recieving the value

```
showNumber(value) {
    const userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
    console.log("value", value);
    userInput.value = value;
  }
```

I have tried "1" but it do not work and feels wrong anyway. I want to pass a number, not a string.

Comment: Need code where you pass the supposed number to `showNumber`

Comment: These two code snippets don't interact directly. Did you rename them when copying them into the question? If so, `value` is not the new number, your console log should show you exactly what that object actually is.

Comment: My bad, I have updated the post.

Comment: Your `showNumber` function is being passed the button's click event, not a number.

Comment: I tried to pass the value as parameter to function but that triggers the function every time render triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set onClick to a function that calls your function with the value you want:

```
<button onClick={() => {this.showNumber(1)}}>one</button>
<button onClick={() => {this.showNumber(2)}}>two</button>
<button onClick={() => {this.showNumber(3)}}>three</button>
```

You may need to bind this.showNumber.

Comment: Lovely, this solved the issue.